# Selenium Node not getting connected to Hub while on VPN

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Problem description is like.

System configuration :

Windows 7 64 bit, Java version >1.6, Selenium Grid Jar 2.52.0.

1. This issue observed only when I am connected to VPN and using Java version >1.6
2. Selenium Node getting exception Java.net.socketException : could not register this node.Permission denied.
3. This scenario is observed when using java version >1.6.
4. Everything works fine when I am not connected to VPN.
5. I have tried using different port but nothing works.

Comment: well isn't point 2 clear.."permission denied"..you do not have permission to connect through VPN

Comment: this works fine when I do have Java 1.6 version. For java version >1.6 its giving permission denied.

Comment: Nope..that cannot be the case..I m quite sure it has nothing to do with the java versions..be it java 1.6, 1.7, 1.8...share a unit test that will reproduce this issue then lets see